# http.post always entering error callback in IE8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools, angular-http

I have a simple Angular service that works fine in FireFox, Safari, Chrome and IE9+

However, for IE8, the service is always hitting the .error callback.

JS:

```
myService.authUser($scope.data)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Success..");
        $scope.showProfile = true;
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("ERRROR!!!");
        $scope.errorText = true;
    })

app.service('myService', function($http) {


    this.authUser = function (myData) {
        return $http({
            url: 'url',
            method: "POST",
            data: angular.toJson(myData),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    };
});
```

In the above scenario, IE8 is always logging ERRROR!!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the url you are hitting responds with the correct status code EG : 200, 404 etc

For example if your backend is .NET MVC

```
public ActionResult TestError(string id) // id = error code{
Response.StatusCode = 400; // Replace .AddHeader
var error = new Error();  // Create class Error() w/ prop
error.ErrorID = 123;
error.Level = 2;
error.Message = "You broke the Internet!";

return Json(error, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);}
```